# Обработать результаты поиска по БД

Tags: android, база-данных, поиск

Есть код, который ищет совпадения вводимого текста и текста из двух колонок БД. Можно ли обрабатывать результаты поиска таким образом, чтобы после нажатия на результат открывать активность по _id?

Вот сам код активности:

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FilterQueryProvider;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper sqlHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Cursor userCursor;
    SimpleCursorAdapter userAdapter;
    ListView userList;
    EditText userFilter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
        userList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ppvsList);
        userFilter = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ppvsFilter);

        sqlHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        // создаем базу данных
        sqlHelper.create_db();
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        try {
            db = sqlHelper.open();
            userCursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE, null);
            String[] headers = new String[]{DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME, DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NUMBER};
            userAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
                    userCursor, headers, new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2}, 0);

            // если в текстовом поле есть текст, выполняем фильтрацию
            // данная проверка нужна при переходе от одной ориентации экрана к другой
            if(!userFilter.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                userAdapter.getFilter().filter(userFilter.getText().toString());

            // установка слушателя изменения текста
            userFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }

                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
                // при изменении текста выполняем фильтрацию
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                    userAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
                }
            });

            // устанавливаем провайдер фильтрации
            userAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
                @Override
                public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {

                    if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {

                        return db.rawQuery("select * from " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE, null);
                    }
                    else {
                        return db.rawQuery("select * from " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE +
                                        " where " + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME + " like ?" +
                                        " or " + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NUMBER + " like ?",
                                new String[]{"%" + constraint.toString() + "%", "%" + constraint.toString() + "%"});
                    }
                }
            });

            userList.setAdapter(userAdapter);
        }
        catch (SQLException ex){}
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        // Закрываем подключение и курсор
        db.close();
        userCursor.close();
    }
}
```

Хочу добавить переход на другую активность через:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Read.class);
                intent.putExtra("head", X);
                startActivity(intent);
```

Где X - это _id

Разметка лайаота поиска:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText android:id="@+id/ppvsFilter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Поиск" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ppvsList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

UPD: Задача упрощается, обработчик завел через

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(SearchActivity.this, Read.class);
                intent.putExtra("head", X);
                //запускаем вторую активность
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Как этому обработчику подкинуть X, которым должен быть _id найденного результата ??

Comment: У вас же в обработчик приходит параметр `long id`. Это и должен быть ваш `_id`.

Comment: А как вытащить его значение, чтобы его можно было использовать?

Comment: Ну вместо `X` напишите `id` в обработчике...

Comment: не выходит, тот же эффект ((